# Mysql sub query with MAX

Tags: mysql, max

I'm trying to speed up a query which currently takes 1.2 seconds to run. The query is:

```
select 
process.exchange,
process.market,
process.volume,
process.bid,
process.ask,
(select MAX(last) FROM a where a.exchange = process.exchange 
AND a.market = process.market 
AND a.created_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE LIMIT 1) as Ask1,
Ask2,
((Ask2 / (select MAX(last) FROM a where a.exchange = process.exchange 
AND a.market = process.market 
AND a.created_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE LIMIT 1 ))
 * 100) - 100 as percentage
FROM process
WHERE process.exchange IN('BLAH','BLAH2')
ORDER BY percentage ASC
```

Table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `exchange` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `market` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `volume` double UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `bid` double NOT NULL,
  `ask` double UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `last` double NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `a`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `market` (`market`),
  ADD KEY `exchange` (`exchange`),
  ADD KEY `created_date` (`created_date`);

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


CREATE TABLE `process` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exchange` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `market` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `volume` double NOT NULL,
  `bid` double NOT NULL,
  `ask` double NOT NULL,
  `Ask2` double NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `process`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `created_date` (`created_date`),
  ADD KEY `exchange` (`exchange`),
  ADD KEY `market` (`market`);

ALTER TABLE `process`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I need to work out the percentage change between `Ask1` and `Ask2`. `Ask1` information is in another table called `a` that has lots of rows of the prices for each market and exchange.

This is how the data in table "a" looks like:

```
Exchange  Market Volume Bid Ask Last Created Date
BLAH      APL      3000 1.2 1.3 1.3  2017-07-26 16:31:00
BLAH      APL      3000 1.4 1.5 1.45 2017-07-26 16:30:00
```

I need `Ask1` to get information from here getting the highest value in the last 5 minutes. So the sub query I got is:

```
select MAX(last) 
  FROM a 
 where a.exchange = process.exchange 
   AND a.market = process.market 
   AND a.created_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE 
 LIMIT 1
```

I need to select it and also do a calculation with it so at the moment I have to have the sub query there twice.

The `MAX` seems to slow down the sub query a lot.

This is what EXPLAIN says:

```
id select type table   partitions type  possible keys key  key_len ref  rows filtered Extra
1 PRIMARY     process NULL       ALL   exchange      NULL NULL    NULL 272 99.63 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY a NULL      ref   market,exchange,created_date market 47 cms.process.market 1603 0.17 Using index condition; Using where
3 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY a NULL      ref   market,exchange,created_date market 47 cms.process.market 1603 0.17 Using index condition; Using where
```

The "a" table has about a million rows and "process" table has about 630 rows.

Is it possible to speed it up?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). In addition (and not that we're quite there yet), but questions about query performance generally need to provide an EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will provide the information from the link post and update my question.